# Remove Key Value pair from jsonb nested array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have jsonb data as

```
{
  "a":[
    {"b":1,"c":2,"d":3},
    {"b":4,"c":5,"d":6}
  ],
  "g":[
    {"b":1,"c":2,"d":3},
    {"b":4,"c":5,"d":6}
  ]
}
```

I want to remove c key from nested array in both "a" and "g" keys. Is there a single query to perform this?

Comment: not sure you can update it as is (unless you create a function for specifically this. You can recreate your jsonb by expanding it, removing unnecessary elements and aggregate it back - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d1e8617aa77195ffb6cbe8a0da73af50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e3720f59a5912375be8fbdf8c440b215)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(key, a)                                -- 5
FROM (
    SELECT
        mydata,
        key,
        jsonb_agg(a_elems.value - 'c') as a                   -- 3/4
    FROM
        mytable,
        jsonb_each(mydata) elems,                             -- 1
        jsonb_array_elements(elems.value) AS a_elems          -- 2
    GROUP BY mydata, key                                      -- 4
) s
GROUP BY mydata                                               -- 5
```

1. Expand the JSON elements into one row each. This generates two columns: One for the key and one for the value (the JSON array)
2. Expand the JSON array into one row each (which separates the aggregated JSON object from which you want to remove the `c` element)
3. You can use the `-` operator to remove the element.
4. To reaggregate the original JSON object, you need to group it backwards. `jsonb_agg()` reaggregates the arrays
5. Finally you need to rebuild the original JSON object with `jsonb_object_agg()` using the previously generated key column and the new array column.

Comment: OP has `jsonb` data, so you probably want to change all these `json_*` functions to their equivalent `jsonb_*`.

Comment: @GMB Thank you. I really missed it. Changed!

Comment: Looks good now. Feel free to add [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8329acc6decbe1fff02e9a797acdc2f2) to your answer.

Comment: Oh sorry did not notice the link.

Comment: Looks good. But I am using Postgres 9.4. How can we achieve same result for this version?. As per docs, jsonb_agg does not exist

Comment: You can cast into type json and then use json_agg instead. In a previous version Idid this with type json https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=274ab5f920d31893d2914c5e6e5a18c5

Comment: Sorry in my previous comment, I forgot to add that '-' operator is not supported in postgres 9.4. Getting this error ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb - unknown
LINE 4:     a_elems.value::jsonb - 'c' as a
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

How can we achieve this result?

Comment: In that case you need an additional expanding step: Expanding the inner-most JSON objects into one row each. Afterwards you are able to filter the elements with a simple WHERE clause and reaggregate everything: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e55d3747039a304f92c3e5fc10e852e0 Nevertheless, I strongly recommend to upgrade your database version!